# Sum array of objects by unique keys

Tags: javascript, array

I have an array of objects, each with a `dimensions` field for storing various metrics related to the object, e.g. length, width, weight, etc.  Each object may be different in terms of what metrics it has.

I have a solution but not sure if it's optimal.

```
let dimensions = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, { a: 2, c: 1, d: 3 }, { b: 1, e: 8, f: 1 }]

// get all keys
let dimensionsFields = _.map(dimensions, Object.keys);
// => [[a, b, c], [a, c, d], [b, e, f]]

// flatten
dimensionsFields  = _.flatten(dimensionsFields );
// => [a, b, c, a, c, d, b, e, f]

// filter out duplicates
dimensionsFields  = _.uniq(dimensionsFields );
// => [a, b, c, d, e, f]

// init return data
let dimensionsData = {};

// loop through available metrics, add up the values
dimensionsFields.forEach(field => {
  dimensionsData[field] = _.reduce(dimensions, function(a, b) {
    return a + b[field];
  }, 0);
});
// => { a: 3, b: 3, c: 4, d: 3, e: 8, f: 1 }
```

Comment: As written your code doesn't run, I imagine _ is lodash, but metrics isn't defined (I guess it should be dimensions), but then this still doesn't work for me.

Comment: sorry, i changed some var names and missed that one.  fixed

Comment: It still doesn't work for me, I get that every key has value NaN, which isn't too surprising since for instance we do a + b["d"] but d might not be a property of b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean optimal?

Your thing transforms the object lots of times, which is liable to not be very efficient, if that's what you meant.

Here's something that I hope is simple to read that does your task.

```
function sumObjects(obj1, obj2) {
    return Object.keys(obj2).reduce(
        (acc, currKey) => ({
        ...acc,
        [currKey]: acc[currKey] ? acc[currKey] + obj2[currKey] : obj2[currKey]
        }),
        obj1
    );
}

const result = dimensions.reduce(sumObjects);
```

The observation is that you just need to see how to do your task for two objects and the rest is just a reduce.

The most efficient thing will likely be just a for loop, like

```
const res = {};
for (const obj of dimensions) {
    for (const key in obj) {
        res[key] = res[key] ? res[key] + obj[key] : obj[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: i was definitely overthinking this problem.  thanks for the help!